# Question on deleting POSIX lock file closed

Tags: discussion

Can someone with Python and POSIX experience checkout the question *[.lock is not deleted automatically after releasing the lock in Linux, but in Windows it is getting deleted. Which behavior is normal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58098634/lock-is-not-deleted-automatically-after-releasing-the-lock-in-linux-but-in-win)*? And advise if it should be reopened.

On the surface it does not seem like a bad question to me. It is pointing out a difference in behavior between Linux and Windows, and asks which behavior is conforming.

I assume file-locks are POSIX file locks. If I am mis-parsing the question, then please ignore this post.

Comment: IMHO, some code demonstrating the issue (aka MCVE) would make the question much clearer...

Comment: It smells like an operating system question. How is that .lock file created? What is releasing the "lock"? Might be clear to pythonagonals but to us regulars it seems off topic or unclear.

Comment: "which of these is normal behavior or good approach to have?" Seems about as opinionated as it gets. "Normal" is situational at best, and "a good approach" is textbook opinion-based. If it was asking, specifically, which is conforming, it would no longer be opinion based.

Comment: @Paul - I think the grammar and formation of the question can be fixed with editing. I was more interested in the technical merit of the question.

Comment: Is the goal to ask only about the technical merit of the question as originally asked (which I do consider iffy), or does this discussion's about extend to the question as-edited?

Answer (score 1):

They're asking about [a Python library](https://pypi.org/project/filelock/).  Rather, their application of a Python library.

The question itself seems to be...confused.  They're thinking that what they're seeing is differing behavior between operating systems, but they're not really showing us what that behavior is.  They say that the lock file isn't deleted automatically on Linux, but from what I'm reading in the documentation...every indication would be that it *is*.

So, at a minimum we're dealing with an implementation detail between two operating systems.  For that we should get some code to go along with this so that we can either:

- see what the OP is seeing, or
- establish that the issue is due to a mistake in their programming.

So right now the question *is* unclear.  Why are they asking about what the convention around file locks is when the root symptom they're experiencing is that their custom file lock file is not being cleaned up?

Comment: See https://github.com/benediktschmitt/py-filelock/issues/31, and the SO question it links at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708885/flock-removing-locked-file-without-race-condition - not deleting lockfiles on UNIX is deliberate, and for the reasons detailed in my answer.